# Aggregate functions no result

Tags: mysql

I have a table that contains the following information

```
date             sales
2011-02-13        1
2011-02-13        3
2011-02-13        2
2011-02-14        1
```

I'm trying to get avarage sales per day. Here is how I try to get the information

```
SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE date BETWEEN MAX(date) AND  MIN(date)
```

The problem is that mysql returns no result. What is wrong ?

Comment: your current intention is currently equal to `SELECT * FROM tbl;`

Comment: I don't get what you are trying to do - with your query date will always be between max and min, so you may remove where condition. Maybe explain in more details the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try reversing `MIN()` and `MAX()`?

```
SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE date BETWEEN MIN(date) AND  MAX(date)
```

From the docs, the value must be >= min (the first expression) and <= max (the second expression):

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_between

Comment: I tried SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE date >= MIN(date) AND date <= MIN(date)

still no result

Answer (score 0):

Dont quite know what aggregation you are after but if its sum of sales then

Select Sum(sales) Where

date between Min(date1) and Max(date2)

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand your query, but I think this is more what you want :

```
SELECT AVG(sales) FROM tbl GROUP BY DAY(date)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need average sales per day:

```
SELECT date, sum(sales) / count(distinct date) FROM tbl GROUP BY date
```